# When have I to use "Prefer margin relative"?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I just see for the first time in the IB editor the option "Prefer margin relative":

[image]

But I don't understand when have I to use it and when not. Can you help me?

Comment: Anyone? :( I don't find any guide on Apple site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is related to the new layoutMargins property of UIView in iOS8.  Rather than relating constraints to the frame (or alignment rectangle), it will relate them to the layout margin.

Comment: Great Jerry! I didn't know of the existence of layoutMargins